# How to find Firebase document field and delete document

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a button that lets a user delete their account. When users signup their email and name is saved to a Firestore collection called users, I want to search in the collection's documents where the uid field is equal to the current user uid then delete that document. Deleting the account works but not the document and I'm not getting any errors, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

TextButton(
         onPressed: () async { 
             try {
               await users
                     .where('uid', isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser!.uid).firestore.doc(users.doc().path).delete();
               await _auth.currentUser!.delete().then((value) => 
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const WelcomeScreen())));
                      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast( msg: error.message.toString(),
                        gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white);
                        } on FirebaseException catch (error) { Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: error.message.toString(),
                        gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white);
                       }
                 },
                      child: const Text( 'Delete', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
  ))
```

Comment: please tell which error you are getting it might help to understand your issue more

Comment: I'm not getting an errors in the debug terminal for some reason

Comment: try out my answer if it doesn't works then let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the problem I was just working on my app and found a similar code so here is the solution. Just declare user id as variable for ease not necessary (optional) like this

```
final uid = _auth.currentUser!.uid; //optional
```

& then use this in your code:-

```
await users.doc(uid).delete();
```

instead of

```
await users
           .where('uid', isEqualTo: _auth.currentUser!.uid).firestore.doc(users.doc().path).delete();
```

and Boom now it works like an charm!!
Hope this works!!